# Flatten list column in data frame with ID column

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

My data frame contains the output of a survey with a select multiple question type. Some cells have multiple values.

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=I(list(1,1:2,1:3)))
df
  a       b
1 1       1
2 2    1, 2
3 3 1, 2, 3
```

I would like to flatten out the list to obtain the following output:

```
df
  a       b
1 1       1
2 2       1
3 2       2
4 3       1
5 3       2
6 3       3
```

should be easy but somehow I can't find the search terms. thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can just use `unnest` from "tidyr":

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(df, b)
#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 1
# 3 2 2
# 4 3 1
# 5 3 2
# 6 3 3
```

Comment: thank you! perfect, i'd looked at tidyr but not found this particular case

Comment: The OP said that it should be easy, and you've proven that it truely is that easy! Nice work!

Answer (score 7):

Using `base R`, one option is `stack` after naming the `list` elements of 'b' column with that of the elements of 'a'.  We can use `setNames` to change the names.

```
stack(setNames(df$b, df$a))
```

Or another option would be to use `unstack` to automatically name the list element of 'b' with 'a' elements and then do the `stack` to get a `data.frame` output.

```
stack(unstack(df, b~a))
```

---

Or we can use a convenient function `listCol_l` from `splitstackshape` to convert the `list` to `data.frame`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
listCol_l(df, 'b')
```

Comment: Nice work. I always love seeing simple, elegant base solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way, with `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
data.table(df)[,as.integer(unlist(b)),by=a]
```

If `b` is stored consistently, `as.integer` can be skipped. You can check with

```
unique(sapply(df$b,class))
# [1] "numeric" "integer"
```

Comment: `df$b[1] <- list(1L)` us too manual and inpractical if the OP has many such entries. I think something like, `data.table(df)[,as.integer(unlist(b)),by=a]` should do

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah, or ingest the data into R "correctly" (in the sense of storing as integers up front). I'll switch to what you've written.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another base solution, far less elegant than any other solution posted thus far. Posting for the sake of completeness, though personally I would recommend akrun's base solution.

```
with(df, cbind(a = rep(a, sapply(b, length)), b = do.call(c, b)))
```

This constructs the first column as the elements of `a`, where each is repeated to match the length of the corresponding list item from `b`. The second column is `b` "flattened" using `do.call()` with `c()`.

As Ananda Mahto pointed out in a comment, `sapply(b, length)` can be replaced with `lengths(b)` in the most recent version of R (3.2, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: In the most recent version of R, you can swap out `sapply(b, length)` with `lengths(b)`.

Comment: to get a data.frame back, you'd probably better use: `with(df, data.frame(a = rep(a, lengths(b)), b = unlist(b)))`

Answer (score 0):

A base R approach might also be to create a new `data.frame` for each row and `rbind` it afterwards:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=I(list(1,1:2,1:3)))
df

df <- lapply(seq_along(df$a), function(x){data.frame(a = df$a[[x]], b = df$b[[x]])})
df <- do.call("rbind", df)
df
```