# Transforming a list in a dataframe to a character

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which was scraped from JSCON.

```
store <- fromJSON(txt='https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/epuu/listings/active?api_key=Redacted')
store_json <- as.data.frame(store$results)
```

However, when I go to export the dataframe `store_json` it produces an error

```
Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

Now I understand that this is because there is a list within the data.frame. When I inspected the vector I found there were lists, with elements such as `c("Jewelry", "Earrings", "Dangle & Drop Earrings")`. When I try and use `unlist(vector)` it does not work. Would `gsub` work? Perhaps the paste function then remove the `c()`? I have tried `tostring` and although the vector does become a character when I export as a csv it does not work correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Flatten list column inside data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30243510/903061), or  [Expand list in data frame into additional rows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34210669/903061) or from earlier today [how to flatten data frame that contains lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34206003/903061).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the jsonlite package...

http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/jsonlite/html/unbox.html

You could do this.. I'm sure there's a better way..

```
store <- fromJSON(txt='https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/epuu/listings/active?api_key=Redacted', flatten = TRUE)
z <- toJSON(store, auto_unbox = TRUE)
store_json <- as.data.frame(z$results)
```