# Sorting Interior of a column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to sort the interior of a column in R. For example I have this:

```
ID     HoursAvailable
1      a,b,c,k,d
2      e,g,h
3      a,b,c,h,d
```

And I am trying to sort the numbers in the column internally like this

```
ID     HoursAvailable
1      a,b,c,d,k
2      e,g,h,,
3      a,b,c,d,h
```

I have tried to use the separate function like this:

```
cdMCd<- cdMf %>% separate(HoursAvailable, c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"))
```

But I cannot get it to sort correctly. For this example e in ID 2 would be sorted into the a column, but I need it sorted into the e column. I was planning to separate all the hours into separate columns, order, then recombine, but I cannot get them to separate correctly.

Comment: It's way easier to work with the long version of such a dataset. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243510/flatten-list-column-in-data-frame-with-id-column) for some tips on doing this. there are dozens of similar posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

dt = read.table(text="
ID     HoursAvailable
1      a,b,c,k,d
2      e,g,h
3      a,b,c,h,d
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

SortString = function(x) {paste0(sort(unlist(strsplit(x, split=","))),collapse = ",")}

dt %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Updated = SortString(HoursAvailable)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      ID HoursAvailable   Updated
#   <int>          <chr>     <chr>
# 1     1      a,b,c,k,d a,b,c,d,k
# 2     2          e,g,h     e,g,h
# 3     3      a,b,c,h,d a,b,c,d,h
```

Comment: Worked great, I did not think of creating a function

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I will do:

First create a function that can sort a single one and then create a function that can apply such function to a vector of strings
    library(stringr)
    library(plyr)

```
split_and_sort <- function(x){
   x_split <- sort(unlist(str_split(x, ",")))
   return(paste(x_split, collapse = ","))
}

split_and_sort_column <- function(x){
   laply(x, split_and_sort)
}

df$HoursAvailable <- split_and_sort_column(df$HoursAvailable)
```