# flatten list column within dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, lapply, purrr

I have a data frame with two columns containing lists.

```
test <- data.frame(var_1 = c("ONE", "TWO"))

test$var_2 <- c(list(data.frame(Date = c("Date 1", "Date 2")), list(data.frame(Date = c("Date 3", "Date 4", "Date 5")))))                   
test$var_3 <- c(list(data.frame(Name = c("Name 1", "Name 2")), list(data.frame(Date = c("Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5")))))
```

I'd like to loop over the lists to create a flattened data frame, repeating var_1 for the length of the list of each row

## Desired Output

```
data.frame(var_1 = c("ONE", "ONE", "TWO", "TWO", "TWO"),
           Date = c("Date 1", "Date 2", "Date 3", "Date 4", "Date 5"),
           Name = c("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5"))


  var_1   Date   Name
1   ONE Date 1 Name 1
2   ONE Date 2 Name 2
3   TWO Date 3 Name 3
4   TWO Date 4 Name 4
5   TWO Date 5 Name 5
```

I tried applying some of the proposed solutions like using `unnest` from this post [Flatten list column in data frame with ID column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243510/flatten-list-column-in-data-frame-with-id-column) but this didn't quite give me my desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option where we `unlist` the 'var_2', 'var_3', and `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
test %>% 
    group_split(var_1) %>%
    map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
                mutate_at(-1, ~ list(unlist(.))) %>% 
                unnest(c(var_2, var_3)))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  var_1 var_2  var_3 
#  <fct> <fct>  <fct> 
#1 ONE   Date 1 Name 1
#2 ONE   Date 2 Name 2
#3 TWO   Date 3 Name 3
#4 TWO   Date 4 Name 4
#5 TWO   Date 5 Name 5
```

---

Or  we can do

```
test %>%
     rowwise %>%
     summarise_all(~ list(unlist(.))) %>%
     unnest(cols = everything())
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  var_1 var_2  var_3 
#  <fct> <fct>  <fct> 
#1 ONE   Date 1 Name 1
#2 ONE   Date 2 Name 2
#3 TWO   Date 3 Name 3
#4 TWO   Date 4 Name 4
#5 TWO   Date 5 Name 5
```

---

Or with

```
test  %>% 
    group_by(var_1) %>%
    nest %>% 
    mutate(data = map(data, ~ summarise_all(.x, ~ list(unlist(.))) %>% 
    unnest(everything())))   %>% 
    unnest(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
setDT(test)[, c(.(var_1=var_1), do.call(cbind.data.frame, list(var_2, var_3))), var_1][, 
    (1L) := NULL][]
```

output:

```
   var_1   Date   Name
1:   ONE Date 1 Name 1
2:   ONE Date 2 Name 2
3:   TWO Date 3 Name 3
4:   TWO Date 4 Name 4
5:   TWO Date 5 Name 5
```

data:

```
test <- data.frame(var_1 = c("ONE", "TWO"))

test$var_2 <- c(list(data.frame(Date = c("Date 1", "Date 2")), list(data.frame(Date = c("Date 3", "Date 4", "Date 5")))))                   
test$var_3 <- c(list(data.frame(Name = c("Name 1", "Name 2")), list(data.frame(Name = c("Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5")))))
```